# How can we change the Datatype of the Excel cell to CellValues.String from c#

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, excel-2007

how can we change the    DataType = CellValues.String, of each excel column from c#.

```
for (int index = 0; index < NoOfRecords; index++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
    {                            
      mWSheet1.Cells[(rowCount) + index, j + 1] =Convert.ToString(ResultsData.Rows[index][j].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a string format("'"+) in frond of each collection

```
for (int index = 0; index < NoOfRecords; index++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
    {                            
      mWSheet1.Cells[(rowCount) + index, j + 1] ="'"+Convert.ToString(ResultsData.Rows[index][j].ToString());
    }
}
```